# javascript questions

Tags: javascript, dom

Today I am going to attend a seminar on basic java script. Can anyone give me some good question /answers which I can ask in query session ?

Seminar will cover : intro to java script,History ,Validation, browser compatibility, events,DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask about browser detection vs. feature detection. That's always good for a lively discussion, and is typically informative on the basics behind decent javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stir up trouble:
What's the best library framework to use?

Comment: Don't ask this. If a seminar on "basic" JS mentions any libraries, it's probably a bad seminar and you should ask for your money back.

Comment: That's just asking for trouble :)